# Why Process exec() did not return result?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

when I'm trying to run JUnit tests through cmd with executing commands. It seems to work properly writing directly in cmd, but when I try to execute the same commands with Process nothing happens. Here's some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] commands = new String[5];
    commands[0] = "cmd";
    commands[1] = "/c";
    commands[2] = "cd src_folder_path";
    commands[3] = "javac -cp .;lib/junit-4.12.jar ./models/java_file_toCompile.java .....";
    commands[4] = "java -cp .;lib/junit-4.12.jar.;lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar TestRunner";

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
        BufferedReader inStreamReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())
        );
        while (inStreamReader.readLine() != null) {
            System.out.println(inStreamReader.readLine());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you intending to print every other line? If not, why do you call `readLine` twice?

Comment: It is recommended to use Process Builder instead of the older utility Runtime.getRuntime.exec().

Comment: Please clarify what does it mean by "Nothing happens", and what does it suppose to print?

Comment: First of all it must create .class/compiled/ files from the "javac" command

Comment: Ok I found the error, all commands must be at commands[2], separated with "&&", "&" etc. Thanks.

Comment: That's not the only problem by a long shot.